# Blender 2.8 exporting UV-Layout

Tags: uv-image-editor

I've found the button i should use for that, but somehow they changed it from "UVs" to "UV", now the "Export UV Layout" button is missing and i can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is there in the UV menu on top, maybe update blender?
If you can't find it, you should be able to search it by name with F3 key on 2.8
I can find it by typing export uv.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Searching it with F3 works

Comment: In case you _still_ can't find it, make sure you did not disable the "Import-Export: UV Layout" Add-on in Preferences.